# Does New Orleans, LA have a bike share?

Tags: public-transport, bicycles, new-orleans

I'm wondering if an easy street-side bike-share option is available in New Orleans, in Autumn this year. If so, what's it called and where can I find more info such as pick-up/drop-off locations, availability & costs?

Examples include [NYC's Citi Bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citi_Bike), [Chicago's Divvy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divvy), or [Boston's Hubway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubway).

Comment: Welcome to TSE. One of the expectations of StackExchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research (such as a web search). The short answer is that New Orleans does not have a bikeshare; the city only released an RFP in April of this year. http://www.nola.gov/mayor/press-releases/2016/20160419-pr-bicycle-share-rfp-released/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet. The City has [put out for bid](http://bikeeasy.org/advocacy/bikeshare_new_orleans/) a 700 bike system with initial plans to open [in 2017](http://www.bestofneworleans.com/gambit/new-orleans-hopes-to-launch-a-privately-funded-bike-share-program-by-2017-what-do-you-think/Poll?poll=2929174) and [work is underway](http://www.nola.gov/bike-share/) to make that happen, including a recently completed "preview" with 35 bikes.

There are, of course, [bike rental](https://www.google.com/search?q=new%20orleans%20bike%20rental&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) options available in the meantime.

Comment: Updated information on bike share in New Orleans: http://www.nola.gov/bike-share/

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no single system like CitiBike in NYC for New Orleans, but they have plenty single bike shops for short rentals. I've seen a lot close to Mississippi and in French Quarter. Anywhere around $30-50/day.